# StructureMap Exception Code: 205 while trying to put an AppSettings value in constructor

Tags: structuremap

I'm having trouble adding a value to my ImageService constructor.
My IUserRepository works, but when I try to put "absoluteImagePath" into the constructor (Bootstrapper) I get the following error:

```
StructureMap.StructureMapException:  
StructureMap Exception Code:  205  
Missing requested Instance property  
"absoluteImagePath" for InstanceKey  
"8a15766b-879b-4edb-b060-c868f35aef39
```

ImageService:

```
public ImageService(IUserRepository userRepository, string absoluteImagePath)
{
    _userRepository = userRepository;
    _absoluteImagePath = absoluteImagePath;
}
```

Bootstrapper:

```
For<IImageService>()
    .Use<ImageService>()
    .Ctor<string>("absoluteImagePath")
    .EqualToAppSetting("AbsoluteImagePath");
```

Comment: This should work provided that all classes that depend on ImageService request it as the interface IImageService. Make sure that no references to the concrete ImageService class are in any constructor.

Comment: Yeah, you will have to share more details to get an answer, the code you have shown should work.  Does ImageService have other constructors?  Is it possible there is another place you are passing a parameter called absoluteImagePath?

Comment: I tried the code you provided here and that works like it intend to do, so there is something in your registration that you have not posted here.

If I remove the constuctor part of the registration I get the same error that you get.